# Implement vectorization instead of nested loops on dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataset `('sample_data.csv')` of the form below:

```
timestamp,cell_id,crnti,enodeb_id,uplane_downlink.cqi_wideband_mean,uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km,uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes,time_sec,timestamp_y,uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes
1606208553171,1,1487,1002107,7,27,134,1606208553,1606208553256,146
1606208557195,1,1487,1002107,6,27,388,1606208557,1606208557369,577
1606208557236,1,2631,1002107,10,27,251,1606208557,1606208557351,194
1606208561301,1,1487,1002107,6,27,140,1606208561,1606208561463,245
1606208561339,1,2631,1002107,11,27,159,1606208561,1606208561381,108
1606208565415,1,1487,1002107,7,27,99,1606208565,1606208565472,54
1606208565435,1,2631,1002107,10,27,64,1606208565,1606208565495,54
1606208569518,1,1487,1002107,6,27,101,1606208569,1606208569601,289
1606208569533,1,2528,1002107,7,16,57,1606208569,1606208569621,0
1606208571263,1,2631,1002107,10,27,0,1606208571,1606208571263,8500
1606208573557,1,2528,1002107,8,16,0,1606208573,1606208573557,0
1606208575838,1,1487,1002107,7,27,0,1606208575,1606208575838,50
```

Here the column `crnti` represents an user and the column `time_sec` gives a timestamp for this user's session. Sessions that are separated by less than 9 secs are considered continuation (small session of a longer session). My end goal is to summarize session properties for each user. In the summary I want to show

1. Session duration → calculated as  `(last = max(time_sec)) - (first=min (time_sec))` for a dataframe that is a filtered DF (including only records that are less than 9 sec apart) for a crnti.  In the code below I do it as:

   ```
   session_summary['session_duration'] = int(session_summary['last'])-int(session_summary['first'])
   ```
2. Sum of `uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes` across all small sessions for a user → calculated as sum of all values in the filtered df (session_summary):

   ```
   session_summary = sub_session.astype(int).groupby(['crnti', 'cell_id', 'enodeb_id']).agg(distance_initial_km = ('uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km', 'mean'),
                                                                                              first = ('time_sec', 'min'),
                                                                                              last = ('time_sec', 'max'),
                                                                                          cqi = ('uplane_downlink.cqi_wideband_mean', 'mean'),
                                                      non_gbr_dl_bytes = ('uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes', 'sum'),
                                                      non_gbr_ul_bytes = ('uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes', 'sum'))
   ```
3. Sum of `uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes` across all small sessions for a user → calculation described above
4. Mean of `cqi_wideband_mean` → calculation described above
5. Mean of `uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km` → calculation described above

As an example for rnti = 1487. Here is the summary - [image]

I have the following code that gets me the expected output. However my dataset is pretty big (6M rows) and this approach is not scalable and takes way too long. I came across the concept of [vectorization](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) using numpy or pandas and want to implement it, but not sure where to start. Any pointers are appreciated.

Working but slow code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



comb_dl_ul_full_191 = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')


column_names = ['crnti', 'enodeb_id', 'cell_id', 'uplane_downlink.cqi_wideband_mean', 'uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km', 'uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes',
                                                 'time_sec',
                                                 'uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes']

all_sessions_summary = pd.DataFrame()

enbs = [1002107]  ## this is an array. For simplicity I am only showing one element. Creating it as shown below

#enbs = np.unique(comb_dl_ul_full['enodeb_id'].to_list())

comb_dl_ul_full_191 = comb_dl_ul_full_191.astype(int) # converting all to INT


for enb in enbs:
  cells = [1] # this is an array. For simplicity I am only showing one element. Creating it as shown below
    #cells = np.unique(comb_dl_ul_full_191[comb_dl_ul_full_191['enodeb_id']==enb]['cell_id'].to_list())
  for cell in cells:
    dd = comb_dl_ul_full_191[(comb_dl_ul_full_191['enodeb_id']==enb) & (comb_dl_ul_full_191['cell_id']==cell)]
    rntis = np.unique(dd['crnti'].to_list())
    dd.sort_values(by=['time_sec'], inplace=True)
    for rnti in rntis:
      d = dd[(dd['enodeb_id']==enb) & (dd['crnti']==rnti) & (dd['cell_id']==cell)]
      f = d['time_sec'].to_list()
      timedeltas = [int(f[i-1])-int(f[i]) for i in range(1, len(f))]

      session_summary = pd.DataFrame()
      session_summary_overall = pd.DataFrame()

      count=0
      i=0
      while i < len(timedeltas):
          if timedeltas[i] > -9:
            sub_session = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
            d = d[column_names]
            sub_session = sub_session.append(d.iloc[[i]])
            for  j in range(i, len(timedeltas)):
              if timedeltas[j] > -9: 
                sub_session = sub_session.append(d.iloc[[j+1]])
              else:
                break       

            count = int(len(sub_session['time_sec']))
            sub_session.astype(int)
            session_summary = sub_session.astype(int).groupby(['crnti', 'cell_id', 'enodeb_id']).agg(distance_initial_km = ('uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km', 'mean'),
                                                                                              first = ('time_sec', 'min'),
                                                                                              last = ('time_sec', 'max'),
                                                                                          cqi = ('uplane_downlink.cqi_wideband_mean', 'mean'),
                                                      non_gbr_dl_bytes = ('uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes', 'sum'),
                                                      non_gbr_ul_bytes = ('uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes', 'sum'))
            session_summary['session_duration'] = int(session_summary['last'])-int(session_summary['first'])
            session_summary = session_summary.reset_index()
            session_summary_overall = session_summary_overall.append(session_summary, ignore_index=True)
            i=i+count
          else:
            sub_session = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
            sub_session = sub_session.append(d.iloc[[i]])
            session_summary = sub_session.astype(int).groupby(['crnti', 'cell_id', 'enodeb_id']).agg(distance_initial_km = ('uplane_downlink.distance_initial_km', 'mean'),
                                                                                              first = ('time_sec', min),
                                                                                              last = ('time_sec', max),
                                                                                          cqi = ('uplane_downlink.cqi_wideband_mean', 'mean'),
                                                      non_gbr_dl_bytes = ('uplane_downlink.non_gbr_dl_bytes', 'sum'),
                                                      non_gbr_ul_bytes = ('uplane_uplink.non_gbr_ul_bytes', 'sum'))
            session_summary['session_duration'] = 4.096
            session_summary = session_summary.reset_index()
            session_summary_overall = session_summary_overall.append(session_summary, ignore_index=True)
            count = count+1
            i=i+1
      all_sessions_summary = all_sessions_summary.append(session_summary_overall, ignore_index=True)
```

Output using data_set:

```
,crnti,cell_id,enodeb_id,distance_initial_km,first,last,cqi,non_gbr_dl_bytes,non_gbr_ul_bytes,session_duration
0,1487,1,1002107,27,1606208553,1606208575,6.5,862,1361,22
1,2528,1,1002107,16,1606208569,1606208573,7.5,57,0,4
2,2631,1,1002107,27,1606208557,1606208571,10.25,474,8856,14
```

Comment: Those variable names, woof. I'm looking at it and tbh it's a mess. Can you clarify how each of those 5 variables you want should be calculated? Like what does session duration mean in terms of the sample data? If I can get a better handle on what you're calculations look like I can try and write some vectorized versions from scratch for you to see. Maybe not all of them but enough to get you started on syntax and general approach

Comment: @Coupcoup - sorry for the long names. thanks for looking into this. I will add some info re calculations for the variables

Comment: @Coupcoup - Please let me know if you need any other clarifications. Again thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Looks a lot better. I just finished answering another question on vectorised processing if you want to check that out in the meanwhile otherwise I can give this a go tomorrow

Comment: Ack, thanks. Will take a look

Comment: @Coupcoup - Looked at ur other answer for vectorisation. trying to adapt my logic. No success yet. Will keep trying

Comment: Alright, got some more free time today on this cooped-up thanksgiving. Let me give it a shot

Comment: This first line `comb_dl_ul_full_191 = comb_dl_ul_full_191.astype(int)` throws `comb_dl_ul_full_191 is undefinied`. I managed to organize some of the later code while watching some gilmore girls with the gf but I need to know what that's supposed to be set to initially to actually run it and test performance improvements

Comment: lol. thanks a lot. you can assume `comb_dl_ul_full_191` to be the sample dataset that I provided. You will need to load it as dataframe.

Comment: can you rewrite the first few lines before the `for` statement so that your code runs when you copy-paste it into a new file? I can't get what's posted here to run

Comment: sure, working on it

Comment: @Coupcoup - added some more steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116701/discussion-between-rfguy-and-coupcoup).

Comment: Hey rfguy, you'll need to change the title of your post as it doesn't fit the guidelines of this site. The title should represent what the code does, not what you want reviewed :) Otherwise people can't know if they have experience or interest in helping you! I've taken the liberty of adding the "vectorization" tag to your post, which should get your more visibililty

Comment: @IEatBagels - Noted. Thanks